# How do I process splitting on certain characters with regex

Tags: regex, icu

In my app, I'm trying to split a string into an array based on a regex pattern. I'd like to be able to load my volt templates and run them through our custom rendering engine - just to learn a bit more on how rendering engines work.

I wrote the regex below to do just that:

```
"(?s)(\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}|\\{%.*?%\\}|\\{#.*?#\\})"
```

And this is an example of such a template:

```
# {{ title }}
{{created_at}} {{created_location}}
============
Paragraphs are separated by a blank line.
2nd paragraph. *Italic*, **bold**, and `monospace`.

Itemized lists look like:
{% for (item in items) %}
    * {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, ideally, I'd like this to be converted to an array looking like this:

```
[
    "# ",
    "{{ title }}",
    "\n",
    "{{created_at}}",
    " ",
    "{{created_location}}",
    "\n============\nParagraphs are separated by a blank line\n2nd paragraph. *Italic*, **bold**, and `monospace`.\n\nItemized lists look like:"
    "{% for (item in items) %}",
    "\n* {{ item }}\n",
    "{% endfor %}"
]
```

However, when I run the regex above, I get:

```
[
    "Paragraphs are separated by a blank line.\n2nd paragraph. *Italic*, **bold**, and `monospace`.\n\nItemized lists look like:",
    "{% for (item in items) %}\n* {{ item }}",
    "{% endfor %}\n"
]
```

As you can see the title part completely disappears. Furthermore, there seem to be some issues with the newline characters. Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: You should tag your regex flavor (js, pcre, etc)

Comment: ICU is the one I'm using, sorry.

Comment: Please show the code behind it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ICU so this is very possibly useless, but this gets pretty close in perl.  The main difference being `* {{item}}` being `*` ,`{{item}}`:   `perl -0 -ne '@matches = /(\{(?>[^{}]|(?-1))*\})|([^{}]+)/g; for $m (@matches) {print "${m}XX\n" if $m =~ /\S/ };' matching`

Comment: Everything other than the actual regex is just...output and filtering whitespace out.

Comment: Normally, splitting uses a regex for the *separators* (not the resulting elements). Is that what you want, or must the regex match all results?

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't in the regex, but in the code that I was using to split on the regex. I modified the code below to also return the regex itself.

```
extension NSRegularExpression {
    func split(_ str: String) -> [String] {
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.characters.count)

        //get locations of matches
        var matchingRanges: [NSRange] = []
        let matches: [NSTextCheckingResult] = self.matches(in: str, options: [], range: range)
        for match: NSTextCheckingResult in matches {
            matchingRanges.append(match.range)
        }

        //invert ranges - get ranges of non-matched pieces
        var pieceRanges: [NSRange] = []

        //add first range
        pieceRanges.append(NSRange(location: 0, length: (matchingRanges.count == 0 ? str.characters.count : matchingRanges[0].location)))

        var endLoc: Int = 0
        var startLoc: Int = 0

        //add between splits ranges and last range
        for i in 0..<matchingRanges.count {
            let isLast = i + 1 == matchingRanges.count

            let location = matchingRanges[i].location
            let length = matchingRanges[i].length

            startLoc = location + length

            endLoc = isLast ? str.characters.count : matchingRanges[i + 1].location
            pieceRanges.append(NSRange(location: startLoc, length: endLoc - startLoc))
        }

        var pieces: [String] = []
        var previous: NSRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
        for range: NSRange in pieceRanges {
            let item = (str as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(location:previous.location+previous.length, length:range.location-(previous.location+previous.length)))
            pieces.append(item)

            let piece = (str as NSString).substring(with: range)
            pieces.append(piece)

            previous = range
        }

        return pieces
    }
}
```